# How to access a read-only propertly (re-defined readwrite in class continuation) from a derived class

Tags: objective-c, properties, ios7, derived-class

I am in the following scenario:

I have define a class with a property to access the activeController that i made read-only

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak, readonly) UIViewController *activeController;

@end
```

In the class continuation i have define the property as readwrite as i want to be able to set the active controller only within the class:

```
@interface BaseViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak, readwrite) UIViewController *activeController;

@end
```

How do i make the `readwrite` property accessible from a derived class?

```
@interface ChildViewController : BaseViewController 
@end
```

The compiler only see the property defined as read-only in the derived class and i want to be able to make use of property within my derived class and set the activeview controller in the derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better not to expose publicly an instance variable unless you really need to.

The standard pattern for making some additional parts of the class accessible to subclasses is making a separate header file, e.g. `BaseViewController+Private` with the declaration of `readwrite`. This file can then be included by 'insiders', that is class and it's subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the header file for BaseViewController to

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
{
    __weak UIViewController *_activeController;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak, readonly) UIViewController *activeController;
```

which will allow you to us the following class continuation in the both the base and the child

```
@interface ChildViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak, readwrite) UIViewController *activeController;

@end
```

Comment: i need to make use of activecontroller property in both the base and derived class - should i define both readwrite properties in the base and derived class continuation?